# Postgresql function failed with "relation with OID xxxxx does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, function

I am trying to extend a item profile table by parsering the its part_number column further down into properties. It works fine outside a function.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_item_info
    ADD prop1 varchar(2),
    ADD prop2 varchar(1),
    ADD prop3 numeric(4,3);

UPDATE tbl_item_info
    SET prop1 = substr(part_num,5,2)
    ,   prop2 = substr(part_num,7,1) 
    ,   prop3 = to_number( substr(part_num,8,5) , '9G999')
    WHERE ARRAY[left(part_num,3)] <@ ARRAY['NTX','EXC'] ;
```

But when I try to put the statements into a function. It always fail with error "relation with OID xxxxx does not exist" pointing to the UPDATE statements.

I have no clue what it is trying to say. Any idea why ?

Comment: and if you take `ALTER` statement outside the function?

Comment: Leaving `UPDATE` alone in the function  works. It seems creating (e.g. by `SELECT INTO FROM` a self-joined table, which is created inside the same function ) or changing (`ALTER`) tables which will be queried later inside the same function, both will cause problem. This OID error is not the only error I received. The the self join also failed, simply because it "can't join". After I removed these `SELECT_INTO/DROP/ALTER`. Things works just fine. But I feel so restricted.

Comment: what version you run?..

Comment: 9.6.2 Win7 32bit

Comment: ah... where did you get it from? and when?

Comment: I use sqlworkbench to execute the queries. After I put the above code into a function ? Actually I was about to cherry pick some product data from a CSV, I was trying to wrap all the intermediate table CREATE/DROP, minor data parsing etc  into a single function.

Comment: no,no your version is very new and described behaviour looks like bug, so I assumed that you compiled some in development version

Comment: I've bumped into the same error message but in my case this was related to the fact I was recreating some functions in one `psql` session window and executing them in another. Re-logging in to psql in my "execute" session was all I needed to do for the error to disappear.

Answer (score 2):

I wish I had a definitive answer, but this seems to be related to a known bug in PostgreSQL as described here:

https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/issues/1094

Bear in mind that the greenplum implementation of PostgreSQL is proprietary to Dell EMC, however, the core code issue is likely the same for all major PostgreSQL distributions. I am still researching this to determine if there is a good resolution to the problem. The database in which I experienced a markedly similar error is not the greenplum implementation of PostgreSQL. The error was thrown when I called the pg_relation_filepath() function in a query on an oid that was dynamically obtained from a record in the pg_class table that should have had an associated external file in a subdirectory of the ./base/ path. The error that was thrown was:

ERROR:  relation "pg_toast_34474_index" does not exist

The point here is that for a toast entity to exist, it is supposed to be tied to another relation and acts as a reference to additional files created out on the storage media to accommodate additional data that does not fit into the owning relation's top level file - in this case, most likely a table. But when I search for the owning relation's oid (34474), the owner doesn't exist. Since the owner doesn't exist I think the logic assumes that the toast entity doesn't either, even though it has a record in the pg_class table.

This is as close as I can get to a root cause for now. Although the above link suggests code to improve the issue is supposed to have been released in version 8.3, my database has been upgraded from version 8.1 to version 9.4.7, so it appears that even though code may have improved between those two version to prevent new occurrences of the problem, if the problem was created before the database was upgraded, the newer code does not know how to reassemble the tinker toys left behind from issues created by this apparent bug before the fix was implemented.

At present I am investigating if a PLPGSQL function can wrap and trap the error for all relations so I can identify which ones have the problem (as well as to solve my original problem of determining which relation is hosted in a specific file that the server.postmaster log tells me it is unable to read from - hopefully it is just an index I can drop/create).

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue at server 13.7. It was not at server 14.3.
It happened when I changed the signature (parameters) of the stored procedure:
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function with OID 894070 does not exist

I removed the old procedure and created new one.
But when I called a function which used that procedure it triggered the error.
To fix it I recreated the function which used changed object.

So general rule:
look where error happens, make sure to recreate object that triggers error, and recompile the code which uses it.

Hope it will help.